# Multiple values for a single parameter

Tags: java, parameter-passing

How to pass multiple values to a single parameter for a particular method in java.
e.g. suppose i have a method with single parameter 'childname', that gets names of all the children in a family.
Now how can i pass multiple values to this parameter to get all different names.

```
public String getChildrenNames(String childname)
{
    children= childname+ familyName;
    return children;
}
```

Comment: can you not change the method to accept two params??

Answer (score 1):

You would typically implement this using either an Array, or a Collection.
eg:

```
public String[] getNamesOfChildren()
```

or

```
public Collection<String> getNamesOfChildren()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use var args like below

```
public String getChildrenNames(String... childname)
{
    for(String s:childname)
    {
        children= childname+ s;
    }
    return children;
}
```

example

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(tes("s","d","s"));
    }

    static String tes(String... x)
    {
        String y="";
        for(String s:x)
        {
            y=y+s;
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

**output:** sds

Comment: This obviously doesn't work and the indentation could be better as well.

Comment: why do you think you should append `s` to the array `childname`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the signature of your method, then you can use concatenation, then in your method you can split this parameter for example :

```
String childname = firstname + "," + lastname;
getChildrenNames(childname);
```

so you can split  this parametter to get multiple names,

```
String[] spl = childname.split(",");
```

---

But there are better ways then this, if you can change the signature of your method, so you can create a method which can take an array or list of names instead :

```
public String getChildrenNames(String...childnames) {
```

or

```
public String getChildrenNames(Lis<String> childnames) {
```

You can even create an Object for example :

```
class Person{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Then your method should take an array or a list of Person Object :

```
public String getChildrenNames(List<Person> childname) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As people say you need to pass them as an Array, so your code should be like this:

```
String familyName = "Family";

public String[] getChildrenNames(String[] childnames)
{
    String[] result = new String[childnames.length];
    for(int i=0; i<childnames.length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = childnames[i] + " " +familyName;
    }
    return result;
}

public void main()
{
    String[] childnames = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
    String[] childnamesAux = getChildrenNames(childnames);
}
```

With this your childnamesAux variable should have: {"Name1 Family", "Name2 Family", "Name3 Family"}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   public static String child(String... name){
    String[] array=name;
    String tem;
    if(name.length==1)
        return name[0];
    for(int counter=0; counter<array.length;counter+=2){
        array[0]=name[counter]+name[counter+1];
    }
    tem=array[0];

    return tem;
}
```

now if you call it

```
    child("Paul","walker");
```

the output will be 
        Paul Walker
hope this helped